# DUDA DE MODULO UPDATE SQL CON PYTHON || INCIDENCIA 1054

Tags: mysql, python, sql, python-3.x, update

Realice mi script para actualizar mi BD, sin embargo, me envía un error 1054 Unknown column 'FGT60ETK19070551' in 'where clause'. ¿Alguno de ustedes saben que estoy realizando mal?

```
  def actualizar(Serial_Num ,licencia_vencimiento):
     cursor = conexion.cursor()
     sql = '''UPDATE Inventario SET (licencia_vencimiento = '{}')  WHERE Serial_Num = 
           {}'''.format(Serial_Num ,licencia_vencimiento)
     cursor.execute(sql)
     col_afectada = cursor.rowcount
     conexion.commit()
     cursor.close()
     retur(col_afectada)
          
print(actualizar(FGT60ETK19070551,'2022-08-12'))
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que el valor FGT896544567 va sin comillas alrededor? Como lo estás enviando y como no es un número, lo esta intepretando como un identificador de columna.

Comment: Perdona, fue error en esa linea pero si lleva comillas y es cuando me muestra el error 054 (42S22): Unknown column 'FGT60ETK19070551' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la asignación de parámetros de la consulta sql, estás asignando a licencia_vencimiento el primer valor, es decir, el de Serial_Num  y viceversa.

```
def actualizar(Serial_Num ,licencia_vencimiento):
     cursor = conexion.cursor()
     sql = '''UPDATE Inventario SET (licencia_vencimiento = {lic})  WHERE Serial_Num = 
           {sn}'''.format(sn=Serial_Num , lic=licencia_vencimiento)
     cursor.execute(sql)
     col_afectada = cursor.rowcount
     conexion.commit()
     cursor.close()
     retur(col_afectada)
          
print(actualizar('FGT60ETK19070551', '2022-08-12'))
```

Te recomiendo no usar *format* para evitar posibles vulnerabilidades en las consultas sql, ya que no estás validando la entrada. En su lugar, se recomienda usar el argumento de *execute* que permite el paso de parámetros.

```py
def actualizar(Serial_Num ,licencia_vencimiento):
     cursor = conexion.cursor()
     sql = "UPDATE Inventario SET licencia_vencimiento = %(lic)s WHERE Serial_Num = %(sn)s"
     cursor.execute(sql, {"lic": licencia_vencimiento, "sn": Serial_Num })
     # estas consultas son equivalentes, pero no hacen el uso de argumentos con nombre
     # sql = "UPDATE Inventario SET licencia_vencimiento = %s WHERE Serial_Num = %s"
     # cursor.execute(sql, (licencia_vencimiento, Serial_Num))
     col_afectada = cursor.rowcount
     conexion.commit()
     cursor.close()
     retur(col_afectada)
          
print(actualizar('FGT60ETK19070551','2022-08-12'))
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu apoyo y seguire tu recomendación